# Use .htaccess to hide .php and query name

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been searching all over google and stackoverflow, and have been finding a large number of answers but none seem to work for me.

Basically what I want is to rewrite my url localhost/index.php?page=1 to localhost/1, while still keeping the query alive.

Now, I have managed to remove the .php with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But removing the Query simply does not seem to work.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule doesn't match what you're trying to do. You're telling it to take 1 or more of anything and make it into `blah.php` (like `http://localhost/blah` -> `http://localhost/blah.php`).

You're looking for something like `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]`.

By the way, your language is a bit backwards. You're not rewriting `index.php?page=1` to `localhost/1`; you're rewriting `localhost/1` to `index.php?page=1` (well, really `1` to `index.php?page=1`).

Comment: Thank you, however it is not yet working. I am receiving an 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: @MitchelJager check your Apache error log and see what it says. RewriteRules can be a bit of a bugger to get right without a bit of trial and error. Note that you'll still need the `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteCond` lines.

Comment: "RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters"  Would be the error. I did still include the other two lines.

Comment: It seems like [NC, L] has to be written as [NC,L] (No Space). This removes the error, but it does not do anything. By doing this all I'm getting is a 404 when going to localhost/1, while localhost/?page=1 still works.

Comment: @MitchelJager was just about to say it's probably the space. Try putting a slash before the replacements: `^/(0-9]+)$` and `/index.php?page=1`

Comment: Ah, it was just me being stupid this second time around. My files were located in a subfolder, which I apparently had to include. Thank you very much, everything is working perfectly!

Comment: Let's hope you are still around, how would I get this code to work with letters and symbols as well as numbers? So let's say localhost/webshop